# How to install cool javascript feature in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to install this menu http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/
on my Wordpress site.However the javascript can not be loaded.Here is my murkup

I used the menu as menu.php, i called this using `<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/menu-bar.php' ); ?>` in index.php and the markup

```
<!-- mp-menu -->
            <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
                <div class="mp-level">
                    <h2 class="icon icon-world">All Categories</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                            <a class="icon icon-display" href="#">Devices</a>
                            <div class="mp-level">
                                <h2 class="icon icon-display">Devices</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                        <a class="icon icon-phone" href="#">Mobile Phones</a>
                                        <div class="mp-level">
                                            <h2>Mobile Phones</h2>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">Super Smart Phone</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Thin Magic Mobile</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Performance Crusher</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Futuristic Experience</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                        <a class="icon icon-tv" href="#">Televisions</a>
                                        <div class="mp-level">
                                            <h2>Televisions</h2>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">Flat Superscreen</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Gigantic LED</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Power Eater</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">3D Experience</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Classic Comfort</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                        <a class="icon icon-camera" href="#">Cameras</a>
                                        <div class="mp-level">
                                            <h2>Cameras</h2>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">Smart Shot</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Power Shooter</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Easy Photo Maker</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Super Pixel</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                            <a class="icon icon-news" href="#">Magazines</a>
                            <div class="mp-level">
                                <h2 class="icon icon-news">Magazines</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">National Geographic</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Scientific American</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">The Spectator</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">The Rambler</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Physics World</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">The New Scientist</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                            <a class="icon icon-shop" href="#">Store</a>
                            <div class="mp-level">
                                <h2 class="icon icon-shop">Store</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                        <a class="icon icon-t-shirt" href="#">Clothes</a>
                                        <div class="mp-level">
                                            <h2 class="icon icon-t-shirt">Clothes</h2>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                                    <a class="icon icon-female" href="#">Women's Clothing</a>
                                                    <div class="mp-level">
                                                        <h2>Women's Clothing</h2>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Tops</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                                    <a class="icon icon-male" href="#">Men's Clothing</a>
                                                    <div class="mp-level">
                                                        <h2>Men's Clothing</h2>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="icon icon-diamond" href="#">Jewelry</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="icon icon-music" href="#">Music</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="icon icon-food" href="#">Grocery</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Collections</a></li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-wallet" href="#">Credits</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- /mp-menu -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/classie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/mlpushmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ), document.getElementById( 'trigger' ) );
    </script>
```

The only js feature that worked in my site just.http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/
and now I am getting frustrated

Can someone help me resolve this?
sorry if my english so bad, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but this isn't the recommended way to load js in WordPress. You normally would load scripts using a special WordPress function in your theme's functions.php file.

It's wp_enqueue_script(). More here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

By the way, WP also has its own function that essentially is used where you might use include(). That is [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part). (That wouldn't have anything to do with the js not loading, but just pointing it out.